Construct an explicit biholomorphism between two domains
This problem is from my homework: Construct an explicit biholomorphism between $D_1=\mathbb{C}-\{-x\pm\sqrt{-1}\pi\mid x\ge1\}$ and $D_2=\{x+\sqrt{-1}y\mid -\infty<x<\infty, -\pi<y<\pi\}$.
It is obvious that we can find a biholomorphism between $D_2$ and the upper plane, but the defination of $D_1$ is so strange and complex that I have no idea how to deal with it. Any help would be appreciated.

If your class uses notation $\sqrt{-1}$ for $i$, I have doubts about it already. That being said, what do you find "strange and complex" about the definition of $D_1$, whilst dealing with explicit biholomorphisms? Have you tried drawing a sketch of it?

I think it is "strange and complex" because it is so different from the domains I encountered before, like the plane with a single curve removed. This one removes two rays, making it harder to handle. The problem remains even if I map the infinity to the origin or other points.

$f(z)=e^z+z$ is the biholomorphism from $D_2$ to $D_1$. This comes entirely from attention...
